# Modelsim - Compile button does nothing

Tags: modelsim

When I create a project and add the files all seems to work, but at some point during my development process the Compile All button stops working (they're not grayed out). Clicking them does nothing, not even a Transcript message. No other compile button works either, not even selecting all files, right-clicking them and selecting Compile Selected.

I've tried deleting the files from the project and re-adding them. Closing Modelsim and reopening the project through the *.mpf file.

Is this a bug on my install or is there something possibly incorrect?

Note: If I recreate the project and add the files they compile and simulate just fine. Which has been the way I've been developing.

I hope this is enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I try to run model sim while dropbox is running (my simulation folder is in my dropbox) I have this exact issue.

Try exiting dropbox and recreating your entire modelsim project.

Running modelsim and loading a project from in my dropbox seems to completely corrupt my project.
Even after I close dropbox, and restart modelsim it is still broken and I have to recreate my project.

Hope this helps.